# I get the following error "AADSTS90002 Tenant authorize not found."

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, azure-active-directory, openid, dynamics-365

I'm working on an application to obtain data through 
OAuth of Dynamics 365
to do this use the following example

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Td7Bk3IXJ9s

```
public static async Task Auth()
{
    string URL = "https://grupolg.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/";

    AuthenticationParameters API = AuthenticationParameters.CreateFromResourceUrlAsync(new Uri(URL)).Result;

                                                  //APP KEY, SECRET KEY
    ClientCredential Creds = new ClientCredential("hidden for security", "hidden for security"); 


    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(API.Authority);
    string token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(API.Resource, Creds).Result.AccessToken;

    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0,2,0);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",token);

        HttpResponseMessage res = await httpClient.GetAsync(URL+"/contacts$top=1");
    }
}
```

but I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Which line give failure?

Comment: Did you check with your subscription administrator?

Comment: Based on the error I'd say the authority is wrong. It needs to be e.g. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/your-azure-ad-tenant-id-here`.

Comment: It doesn't give me error in a specific line, the error marks it in time of execution.
 
In the Azure Administrator have only the access to use Dynamics 365.

I already tried it at https://login.microsoftonline.com/ but it marks exactly the same exception.

Comment: juunas is correct. Based on the correlation ID and time provided the logs show you accessed /authorize/oauth2/token not /<tenant_id_here>/oauth2/token

Comment: Corrected, for version v4.4 you must log in through login.microsoftonline.com/your-azure-ad-tenant-id-here as Juunas and Maweeras comment. Attention because /authorize/oauth2/token and /<tenant_id_here>/oauth2/token no longer work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by the ADAL version you're using and how the authority URL is generated.

If you downgrade the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` library version to 3.9.18 you'll be able to connect without problems. There's an [open bug in GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/1346) where you can track its progress or comment to add more information to get a definitive fix for it.

Comment: Corrected, for version v4.4 you must log in through https://login.microsoftonline.com/your-azure-ad-tenant-id-here as Juunas and Maweeras comment.
Attention because /authorize/oauth2/token and  /<tenant_id_here>/oauth2/token no longer work